# "HANDLE" keyword in C

Tags: c, keyword

I'm not sure if the information I'm giving is enough, but can anyone tell me what does this keyword HANDLE signify in C programming?

It is used as:

```
HANDLE x;
```

I couldn't find any reference to it as a datatype or belonging to some library.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751.aspx

Comment: It has nothing to do with C and everything to do with Windows programming as shown by others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no data type `HANDLE` declared in standard C. I can't say for sure but most likely this `HANDLE` is one of the standard [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751.aspx). It would have been introduced by:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

A `HANDLE` is an opaque type used to represent a Win32 object, for example a file, a mutex, an event etc.